# sklearn MinMaxScaler: Inverse does not equal original

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, normalization, feature-scaling

I am using **MinMaxScaler** on a large dataset (2201887, 3) to normalize features. Inversed values does not match originals.
I tested with the target column, first (a), I applied the scaler on 10 values, then did the inverse transformation and I was able to get original values.
Then (b), I inverted 10 normalized values after applying MinMaxScaler on the whole column and results were completely different :
[image]

**Result of (a) :**

[image]

**Result of (b) :**

[image]

How can I have the same normalized and inversed values when used with the whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue as `inverse_transform(b)` threw an error because it was trained on a `(,3)` array but the input is only `(,1)`. Not sure if I typoed or how your code runs.

You could try instantiating a new MinMaxScaler, as I'm not sure if anything weird happens if you refit it.

Comment: Yes I think that was the problem, I used `inverse_transform()` on the whole transformed data that has the shape (,3) and it generated the same original values. Thank you for your help.